# SQL Server: Performance of count() with where clause

Tags: sql-server

This is a query I have

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tbl 
WHERE intCol = @intval 
  AND varcharCol = @varchr 
  AND (datetimeCol BETWEEN @from AND @to)
```

The query is taking 20 seconds on a table with 6 million records. It's very bad for me as the data can be 20 times more. Is there a way to make it faster?

I have a combined index in place on (`intCol`, `varcharCol`, `datetimeCol`) and the execution plan shows an index scan `(cost 91%)` -> `stream aggregate (cost 9%)` -> Compute Scalar `(cost 0%)`

Highly appreciate any help

Comment: Consider an Indexed View http://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/03/24/indexed-materialized-views-in-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: First you could try to put an index on a single **non-nullable** `int` column (something like your **primary key** - an `ID` or something). Since it's only a single, 4-byte `int`, the index will require fewer pages to be read just to determine the number of rows. Or you could use the system catalog views to get an **approximate** count of row in your table

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL Server, you could also consider a column store index which would help, especially considering the date range part of your query.

Comment: @Bas How would an indexed view help in this scenario where you have a wide date range? Unless those froms and tos are finite and much smaller than the raw data, a materialized view isn't going to be aggregating all that much.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the date ranges being passed? Are they fairly close in range, or can they vary wildly? If they follow common patterns and are fairly close together, table partitioning could significantly reduce the amount of rows that need to be scanned.

Comment: in place, of * ,put pkcolumn,then create indexes on intcol,varcharcol,datetimecol.I don't think this is your real query or real situation.What is your real sitation like.why do you want to find count(*). ?

Comment: The date range will usually be 1 day to 3 months. But data is expected to be huge. I'm getting the count so that I can sample 100/200 rows from that (with uniform distribution). I'm using that sampled rows to display a graph. I'll try with the column store index. Thanks Kyle, for suggesting.
I've tried with a count(ID), that doesn't speed up

Answer (score 3):

May I ask what the data types are in your table? Also, what type of machine are you running on?

Something doesn't seem to be adding up. I came up with some test data and ran the query above and the query executes almost instantly, even when running with `maxdop 1`.

Here's my test data:

```
create table dbo.tbl (
    intCol int,
    varcharCol varchar(128),
    datetimeCol datetime);

insert tbl (
    intCol,
    varcharCol,
    datetimeCol)
select top (6000000)
    abs(checksum(newid())) % 100,
    abs(checksum(newid())) % 100,
    convert(datetime, abs(checksum(newid())) % 50000)
from sys.all_columns a
cross join sys.all_columns b;

create nonclustered index uc
    on tbl (intCol, varcharCol, datetimeCol);
```

Below you can choose any combination of numbers as long as they are within the domain of allowable values and you are *almost* guaranteed matches, because the size of the data set is substantial.

```
declare
    @intval int = 50,
    @varchr varchar(128) = '55',
    @from datetime = '1900-01-01',
    @to datetime = '1950-01-01';

set nocount on;
set statistics io on;
set statistics time on;

select count(*) -- select *
from tbl
where intCol = @intval
    and varcharCol = @varchr
    and datetimeCol between @from and @to
option (maxdop 1);

set statistics time off;
set statistics io off;
```

The results show that the execution time is de minimis.

```
-----------
221

Table 'tbl'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.


 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Also, the query plan that I see is similar to what you mentioned in your original post. This is a typical execution plan and cost for a simple query with an aggregate and a where clause.

[image: Query Cost]

Comment: Before changing to use a column store index, are you running these tests from a development machine or your local box? Just wondering if you could be running up against memory constraints and your machine is using virtual memory, i.e. paging, etc. I'm dubious that SQL Server is failing to meet the needs of this query given the right environment. This is exactly the type of thing SQL is designed to do very well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yobik, I'm doing it on a development machine, have a 4GB commit with 8GB physical RAM. The query runs almost instantly on the second time maybe because of cache. I'm wondering how it's working so quickly for you. Can you try running
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
before running the query. This should clear some cache

Comment: Balok -- I just ran this on a different development machine and it's consistent with the other development box that I ran it on previously, e.g. `elapsed time = 2 ms`. Also, ran it with `dbcc dropcleanbuffers;` prior to execution of the query and getting similar results. btw -- the first development box has SSD and the second is using spindles.

Comment: It takes 20 seconds if I clear the cache. I rebuilt the index and it came down to 4 seconds. That's the best I can get from my build system with a SATA drive. I guess i'll stick to a scheduled index rebuild. I cannot go with columnstore index since we're not using Enterprise edition. Thanks a lot for your responses Yobik.

Answer (score 0):

Replace count(@TheIDOfyourTable)

Comment: That's not going to be any faster than `SELECT COUNT(*)`, unless there's a separate non-clustered index on the `TheIDOfyourTable` column alone ....

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this line of code for quick counting

```
SELECT     count(1)
FROM            tbl
```